# Report is not displaying in dashboard html page for qmetry?

Tags: qaf

I downloaded qmetry maven project from github and made workable in my eclipse. Report was working earlier but since yesterday, it not working where I haven't made any changed in any JS or HTML file.

Please help me to solve it.

[image]

Thanks,
Prashant

Comment: Are opening report in Firefox?

Comment: Yes, I am opening it in firefox only.

Comment: Can you please tell me the solution, how can I get report rendered on dashboard page?

Answer (score 1):

It looks from the screenshot that dashboard is not latest. Ideally it should work with old or new dashboard. Are you able to see reports generated under `test-results` directory? you should be able to locate `meta-info.json` file under `tets-results`. If not then because of no reports to display, dashboard is empty.

You can try using latest dashboard by downloading from [qaf-report](https://github.com/qmetry/qaf-report) github repository. Download zip and extract it in your project root, or delete existing `dashboard` directory and `dashboard.htm` file and replace with the latest one that you downloaded.

EDIT:
If you observed it's not working after firefox update with latest firefox follow below steps:

- go to about:config
- set
  security.fileuri.strict_origin_policy:false.
  [image]

Comment: Sure, I will try as you said. As I said earlier, reports were getting generated. And I also checked test result directory where results were present which showing in report earlier

Comment: may be you can try run your test again and see if you are able to view reports. if  you found with latest firefox this issue refer updated answer

Comment: Check updated answer if you are facing issue with firefox latest version (68.0)

Comment: Thanks, I changed flag in config to false and started working. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

**in Chrome**
Create chrome shortcut.
Rename to Dashboard Chrome
Right click -> properties
Append target --allow-file-access-from-files
Example : "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --allow-file-access-from-files
Click ok
Close all chrome instances, then, Open chrome using that shortcut and try to open report in it.

**in Edge Chromium**
Create Edge shortcut.
Rename to Dashboard Edge
Right click -> properties
Append this to the target --allow-file-access-from-files
Example : "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe" --allow-file-access-from-files
Click ok
Close all Edge instances, then, Open Edge using that shortcut and open the dashboard report in it.

If the above don't fix the issue, delete or rename the dashboard.htm file, then re-run the WAF automation.  The file will be re-created with the latest version.